# Is it grammatically correct to put "to" and "within" together in sentence "this is confirmed by experiment to within strict limits"?

Tags: grammar, to-infinitive

[a post](https://www.desy.de/user/projects/Physics/Relativity/SR/light_mass.html) says

> the photon is a massless particle.  According to theory it has energy and momentum but no mass, and this is confirmed by experiment **to within** strict limits.

Is it grammatically correct to put "to" and "within" together like sentence above? If yes, which part of the sentence does "to" serve with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, as unusual as it is to have two prepositions in a row, this sentence is grammatically correct and natural.

The "to..." in the context of "confirmed by experiment" means "to some degree/precision/etc.", for example:

> *This result is accurate to **five decimal places**.*

Expressions that describe the degree of accuracy are often not simple nouns:

> *about/around/within/over/less than... a millimetre*

"Within strict limits" is a prepositional phrase, but here it acts as a noun representing the degree of accuracy.